# Database does not change even with query execution by entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to insert into a table/model with an FK. The output shows that the database has executed the query and all the values seen in the query are correct(i can see them because i have sensitive data logging enabled) But when i check the DB no changes have been added.

Class 1: MultipleChoiceModel

```
    public class MultipleChoiceModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Answer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string? Section { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }
}
```

Class 2: MultipleChoiceFillerModel

```
    public class MultipleChoiceFillerModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int FillerId { get; set; }
        public string Filler { get; set; } = string.Empty;


        public MultipleChoiceModel? MultipleChoiceModel { get; set; }
    }
```

output window message

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[@p0='1' (Nullable = false), @p1='1222' (Nullable = true), @p2='2' (Nullable = false), @p3='1222' (Nullable = true), @p4='3' (Nullable = false), @p5='1222' (Nullable = true)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "MultipleChoiceFillers" ("Filler", "MultipleChoiceModelQuestionId")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1)
      RETURNING "FillerId";
      INSERT INTO "MultipleChoiceFillers" ("Filler", "MultipleChoiceModelQuestionId")
      VALUES (@p2, @p3)
      RETURNING "FillerId";
      INSERT INTO "MultipleChoiceFillers" ("Filler", "MultipleChoiceModelQuestionId")
      VALUES (@p4, @p5)
      RETURNING "FillerId";
```

**This is the code that inserts the entity**
(note: i have the question id hard coded as 1222 here for testing)

```
 public void AddMultipleChoiceFiller(List<MultipleChoiceFillerModel> MultipleChoiceFiller)
        {
            

     //1222 hardcoded here for testing
            MultipleChoiceFiller.ForEach(filler => filler.MultipleChoiceModel = GetMultipleChoiceById(1222));

            _context.MultipleChoiceFillers.AddRange(MultipleChoiceFiller);


            try
            {
                _context.SaveChangesAsync();  
            }
                
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            


        }

        public MultipleChoiceModel GetMultipleChoiceById(int id)
        {
            MultipleChoiceModel filler = new MultipleChoiceModel();
            filler = _context.MultipleChoices
                .Where(i => i.QuestionId == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();


            return filler;

        }
```

Comment: What is your connectionstring?

Comment: First of all, use `await`.

Comment: @HH adding into the MultipleChoiceModel works fine so im sure the connection string is correct.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov It worked when i mad everything an async task and added await. The sad part is that is what i had it to begin with then changed it because i thought it would solve another problem i had. Thank you. If youd like to reply to it as an answer i will select it as a chosen answer